# ViewState is invalid after using Ajax'ed UserControl with WCF

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I made a UserControl that implements the "Like" behavior, facebook style.

When hitting "Like" (or "Unlike"), the control sends a request to an Ajax enabled WCF service, which in turn manually renders the usercontrol and sends the result back to the client.

It all works well, however it causes other controls in the same page to generate the following JavaScript error:

```
Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

URI: http://somesite/ScriptResource.axd?d=GF84PA...
```

The error occurs only if I press the like/unlike buttons, and then tries something on the page that requires a callback, such as paging in a ListView or submitting a comment.

I'm using C#, ASP.NET, .NET 3.5.

Edit:
My code of rendering the UserControl in WCF looks like this:

```
    public string RenderHtml()
    {
        var pageHolder = new Page();
        var formControl = new HtmlForm();
        var userControl = (TControl)pageHolder.LoadControl(userControlPath);

        if (setControlPropertiesDelegate != null)
            setControlPropertiesDelegate(userControl);

        formControl.Controls.Add(userControl);
        pageHolder.Controls.Add(formControl);
        var output = new StringWriter();
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, false);
        var outputString = output.ToString();
        return outputString;
    }
```

I found out that since I'm rendering the control inside a page and a form, a ViewState hidden field is created (and thus sent to the client through WCF).
I added a method just before the return statement, that removes the form tag and the ViewState, so only the rendered control string is being sent. Now it works just fine.

Comment: First, if you disable the viewstate and continue to get the error, then probably is because you make some change on the html page after the render, or you direct write on the page and change some controls. I suggest to find the problem, because even if you disabled it, your continue to have problems with the page and your buttons will not work. I think that the EnableEventValidation="false" will make this message go, but your buttons will not work because of this error.

Comment: Hi, I found out that the problem is with a "ScriptResource.axd" file. I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: This isn't necessarily where the problem is - ScriptResource.axd is just a resource file where ASP.NET's javascript is retrieved from. The fact that the exception comes from `Sys.WebForms...` means it's being thrown by javascript. You might need to edit your question to explain how you're calling the service and what you're doing to the page after you've called it.

Comment: Hey, I noticed that my WCF returns a VIEWSTATE input field (while rendering the UserControl). I removed it and now it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All controls use ViewState to store properties and settings. Even when you turn it off manually, there's still a small amount of ViewState that will be generated internally by the control. If you are returning the rendered control's HTML from a WCF service, then post the page back to the server, the error will be thrown because the Page knows nothing about the control you loaded dynamically when it decrypts the ViewState to rebuild the page.

As you mention in the comment to your question, manually stripping out the ViewState before sending the HTML down to the client will fix your problem.

I highly recommend reading [this article on ViewState](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx) by Dave Reed. It is by far the best explanation of exactly how ViewState works (and what misconceptions you may have about it).